# using bpy.ops.*.view_all

Tags: python

I have this at the end of a function, so every time I execute it, I would like to use view_all for those three area types from whatever area is active. But I get an obvious context error.

```
        bpy.ops.action.view_all()
        bpy.ops.graph.view_all()
        bpy.ops.timeline.view_all()
```

So, how can I use all three from a single context area?

Comment: See http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/35038/1363 and linked questions. You need to override the context (supply a custom context).