# Knife tool with bmesh API

Tags: python, bmesh, knife-tool

I need to find the **intersection** curve between two (open) meshes, and I can do that interactively with the knife tool. In search for a way to do it from a script, I came across the following highly relevant question:
[Using knife_tool from python api](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15256/using-knife-tool-from-python-api)

There is one answer, which simply refers to the BMesh API. However, I find no immediate candidate for the knife_tool from bpy.ops.mesh in bmesh.ops.mesh. Is there a way to script mesh intersection cutting from bmesh, or at all?

The attached screendump illustrates a cut in the cylinder mesh from the intersecting sphere mesh. I obtain it interactively with the cylinder mesh edges selected, then by Ctrl+F and choosing "Intersect (Knife)".

[image]

Comment: some images are welcome please

Comment: I can probably get by with bpy.ops.mesh.intersect. But if BMesh is the future, I would like to know how to do it with bmesh.ops.mesh.

Comment: @Leander, you are more than welcome to add to the question, or present you findings and perspectives!

Answer (score 0):

Could be this?

```
# Select all vertices in Edit Mode
bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='SELECT')

# Do intersect
bpy.ops.mesh.intersect()
bpy.ops.mesh.intersect(mode='SELECT')
```

Comment: Thanks, @cogitas3d. I eventually ended up doing just that. However, that is not a BMesh operation, and it does not end up producing a BMesh. I have to convert the result to a BMesh afterwards.